# @user.visit_count => undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I am doing what I thought was something very simple - finding a user and incrementing an integer.

```
@user = User.where("created_at > ?", Time.now.midnight).select(:visit_count)
@user.visit_count += 1
@user.save(:validate=>false)
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `visit_count' for [#<ActiveLink visit_count: 1>]:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

This seems like a Rails 3 thing - where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why do you use both where and select in your query? And the first query could return an array of users which you need to process differently.

Comment: @tommasop - what's wrong with using where with select? Doesn't this give me just the visit count of the user(s) that were created recently? Or is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query always returns multiple results as an Array.

Just add .first to be sure that you only pick the first result.

```
@user = User.where("created_at > ?", Time.now.midnight).select(:visit_count).first
```

If you want to update many records at the same time, look at update_all method :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all